# Progress bar in Custom View for some limited time period like 5 seconds

Tags: android, progress-bar, spinner

I just want to add spinner (ring) progress bar for some time (5 seconds) in some specific view. After some time i want to disappear this progress bar.

Here is the class file source

```
verify_next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add_friends_verify_account_button1);
progress_verify=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar_verify_friends);
    
    verify_next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            verify_next.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
            progress_verify.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
             
        
        }});
}


    <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progressBar_verify_friends"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:visibility="gone" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     />
```

Now I want to set some time duration for this progress so that it should be disappear.

Comment: use a handler with a delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Handler for this

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progress_verify.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: Thnx Bro But i also want to launch activity...
but after using intent it shows a delay and suddenly launch activity...
and progress bar appear for a while...